# assign variable and test in if statement possible?

Tags: elixir

Look at the following code:

```
    current_user = Plug.Conn.get_session(conn, :current_user)
    unless current_user == nil do
      Logger.info "User #{current_user.id} logged out"
    end
```

This code works but I feel like it's not Elixir-like. Coming from C I am used to something like this:

```
if ((current_user = get_session("current_user")) != NULL) {
  log("User %d logged out, current_user->id);
}
```

So assign and test in the same line. Is that possible in Elixir? 
Am I doing it wrong anyway? Googling round I feel like I should always avoid if statements in Elixir, because there should always be a better - more functional - way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can assign and test in the same line in Elixir:

```
if current_user = Plug.Conn.get_session(conn, :current_user) do
  Logger.info "User #{current_user.id} logged out"
end
```

If you need to have if/else statements, another way of doing it in Elixir without assigning during the test would be to use `case`:

```
case Plug.Conn.get_session(conn, :current_user) do
  nil ->
    # Handle user is not present
  current_user ->
    # Handle user is present
end
```

(The above logic logs that the user has been logged out when the `current_user` is present in the session, which might look confusing but is the expected behaviour according to the code in the question)

Comment: Yes the original code is followed by `put_session(:current_user, nil)` and a redirect.

Answer (score 2):

There is a rule of thumb: if you are using `if`, something went wrong. There are *very* rare occasions where `if` is on the rightful place in Elixir.

As @navinpeiris pointed out, you might use `case` here, but I personally would go with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1). It is really handy construct, once you get accustomed to it:

```
with %User{} = current_user <- Plug.Conn.get_session(conn, :current_user) do
  Logger.info "User #{current_user.id} logged out"
end
```

First of all, the value of the current user is matched against `%User{}` struct, making it safer than just checking it against `nil`. If match happens successfully, the `do` block in `with` is executed. If not, the optional `else` clause does (it’s absent in the example above.)

Clauses in `with` might be joined with commas. The special form has very good documentation (linked above.) I also [wrote a blog post](http://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2017/02/17/either-monad-in-elixir) on it recently.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to pattern matching and assignments in with/1.